# Best practice for maintaining properties/values through the lifecycle of an Android app, persisting them, and accessing them?

Tags: android

I am building my first Android app. I need to add a specific set of headers to each web api call and want them to persist even when the app closes. I implemented them in shared preferences but now I need to drag around a context for every call, which seems like a bad way to do things. I would like to set the values on initialization of the app. Have them usable by the WebAPIHelper object without much trouble, and when the values change, save them. I am using Room so I could save them there.

Is it standard practice to use LiveData or extend the application object to have access to the values for use within an object such as my WebAPIHelper, or is there another, better way? Is it best to persist these values in a database or SharedPreferences?

**UPDATE**

I have seen some examples of extending the application object like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56684226/how-to-implement-global-variables-in-extends-different-from-application-and-a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35765077/correct-way-to-get-the-instance-of-application-in-android). I would want to get the values from sharedpreferences onCreate and save them to sharedpreferences by calling a setXXX, but I haven't gotten that to work.

Also I was concerned about this statement I found in [an article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class):

"Storing data in the Application object is error-prone and can crash your app. Prefer storing your global data on disk if it is really needed later or explicitly pass to your activity in the intent’s extras."

The implication of this would mean that I would need to pass the header values to the WebAPIHelper object all the time. I am passing the context object everywhere now so I guess it's 6 of one vs 1/2 dozen of the other.

The other way to do this might be to extend the AndroidViewModel class in a BaseViewModel, add the properties there from SharedPreferences so they are available through all ViewModels in the app. Has anybody done it this way?

Comment: Are they always the same, or do they change? When they are tied to specific classes you can put them as values in a companion object. 
If they change you can save them in a room Database and observe this database in a viewmodel tied to an activity, i assume you just have 1 activity and maybe many fragments.

Comment: One of them is set when the app is initialized and never changes thereafter unless the app is reinstalled. Others are like global variables. They can be changed but are required for almost everything. Like a subscription. You might have three of them but everything you see is from the perspective of only one of them. You change the subscription and all data you see is related to that subscription.